# MUI styled TS Error : No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I am getting this error:

> No overload matches this call.

How to resolve this error?

I am trying to create custom button. I am able to create button but getting above error.

Here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cdn-g4c2r6?file=/src/btn.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled, Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";

interface DPWButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  "dpw-variant": string;
}

const getStyles = (type: string, theme: Theme) => {
  const commonStyle: object = {};
  const themeStyles = {
    primary: {
      ...commonStyle,
      background: `red`
    },
    default: commonStyle
  };

  return themeStyles[type as keyof typeof themeStyles] || themeStyles.default;
};

const DWButton = styled(Button)<DPWButtonProps>(
  ({ "dw-variant": variant, theme }) => {
    return getStyles(variant, theme);
  }
);

export default DWButton;
```

I am using it like this:

```
 <DWButton dw-variant="primary">nnn</DWButton>
```

Error
[image]

any idea??

Comment: might be a typo
try changing in interface
`dpw-variant` to `dw-variant` since you are using it in your component.

Comment: @Samuel but this not work..!!

Comment: anyone idea ? how to solve this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the typo, the issue is that your `getStyles` function returns a general `object`, whereas MUI `styled` expects a `CSSObject` (or, to be more accurate, in your case, a function that returns said `CSSObject`).

The `styled` function is powerful with a lot of overloads and complex types, but the drawback is indeed that the error message might be so big that it does not fit in the preview, making it difficult to pinpoint the root cause of the problem.

In your case, you can fix it by typing as `CSSObject` instead of plain `object`:

```
import { CSSObject } from "@mui/material/styles";

const commonStyle: CSSObject = {}; // Instead of `object` type
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nAEICuMMEAdgBoO3XnwAKxMOgC+cIiXIABEJ2AB6EMhhYowZABtaDcNHhtUMAJ76sAEyEAVABZYQWIQGEAyl4DyAIwArLHw4WXlSMmVVDS0dPX01C2ssVCMGPm0oAjwsOAARMQB1Lh5+CQgpOCwAD20+W3RS0Qqqljo4TvJbAHcAWgA3ZF1kTLIALjgLXT4Ac3ppOjpcfgs4WawYLysbdABeOAAKKzAsSengOaEYFzdJ51csAEo4PYA+Vg6ulb41lZAQPxtilJt4-EEQvADixpPQunAfmsbo9gbtXp94fCwLpNFBLJN2piiXAAHRk-6Avio9xfYldfx4ADWs2InAakwABpRbBzaZjpAI+fDbFgcpx9DBJhSgTssHzYUt4ZQYJwoHw4Mi3NTUABtE55NBwRlYSwQAgayynM0a25YbUAXTgAB8nTaUbLUCSRWKJQt6MtVvB8iURPx0ckbLZDs1+E8ADyFENlcSSVBvQ58w5sMi9QbDPRjSZDEaZa62sIvd4Y4nK1XqjZbD2HYsFmBlx5POFdRadpa1Jjwb3IcVBpOiehAA)